# Eclipse: Excluding some libraries while extracting others on export to Runnable JAR

Tags: java, jar, export

I'm building a java project that implements Twitter Storm, and I want to extract and package in my custom libraries into the .jar file.  However, if I extract all the required libraries (using the *Extract required libraries into generated JAR*, the .jar ends up being 20mB in size, as opposed to around 200kBs (using the *Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR* option).

Is there any way I can specify which libraries I want to be packaged in?  Ideally, I'd be able to select these to be extracted into the .jar file, while the rest are excluded.  I can't seem to find an option in Eclipse to do this.

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you saying you want some to be packaged in and some to be external?

Comment: Yes.  Some are already on the Linux VMs that I'm running the .jar on, but certain are required to be packaged in.  For efficiency's sake, it would be good to omit the ones that are on the VMs.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to use the option to "Save as Ant script" and then edit the build.xml to remove the jar files that you don't want to have included in.

Dealing with build.xml files in Eclipse is very easy/natural.  If you do show view/Ant, and then drag the build.xml from the package explorer to the ant view, you can just double click on it.  Much easier than going through the export dialog e very time.